# How di I turn my class into an Entity in Room Persistence?

Tags: android-room

This is my first time using Room Persistence Library and I am having difficulties understanding the concept of entity.

So I have these two classes:

```
public class CapturedTime
{

    @SerializedName("startTime")
    @Expose
    private Long startTime;
    @SerializedName("endTime")
    @Expose
    private Long endTime;}
```

and

```
public class CapturedItem implements Parcelable {

private String serialNumber;
private CapturedTime firstCapturedTime;
private CapturedTime secondCapturedTime;}
```

I believe it's pretty straightforward for the CapturedTime class but I have no idea what I should do for the CapturedItem class. Can I just make the CapturedTime variables into columns or are there steps that I should do first?

Answer (score 0):

First add dependency in `buid.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
        def room_version = "2.1.0-rc01"

        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
        annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
}
```

After that use `@Entity` annotation to declare normal POJO class as entity in Room persistence library.

```
@Entity(tableName = "your_table_name")
public class CapturedTime{
    @SerializedName("startTime")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time")
    private long startTime;
    @SerializedName("endTime")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "end_time")
    private long endTime;
}
```

`@ColumnInfo` used to declare column name in table, by default column name is variable name if you do't provide `@ColumnInfo` annotation

If you want to store custom object in room you use 
 `@TypeConverters()` annotation

In your case,

```
@TypeConverters(CapturedTime.class)
private CapturedTime firstCapturedTime;
```

For more information please visit [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0)

Comment: ahhhh I see, so pretty much the same for CapturedItem class but add TypeConverters annotation for the CapturedTime variable right?